# Singular Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to simplify the following integral but getting no answer. Any help in how to get the resulting function as a function of t would be much appreciated?

`t - Integrate[Abs[t - s]^(-1/2)*s, {s, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to give [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) an assumption:

```
t - Integrate[Abs[t-s]^(-1/2)*s,{s,0,1}, Assumptions->t ∈ Reals] //TeXForm
```

> $t-\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \frac{2}{3} \left(2 (-t)^{3/2}+2 \sqrt{1-t} t+\sqrt{1-t}\right) & t\leq 0 \\
>  -\frac{2}{3} \left(-2 t^{3/2}+2 \sqrt{t-1} t+\sqrt{t-1}\right) & t\geq 1 \\
>  \frac{2}{3} \left(2 t^{3/2}+2 \sqrt{1-t} t+\sqrt{1-t}\right) & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just have a question, do you have an idea how to find a numerical solution for ```Integrate[Abs[t - s]^(-1/2)*u(s), {s, 0, 1}]``` assuming that we dont know the solution ``u``?

Comment: @Mutaz, better to ask a new question (referencing this answer) than request additional help in the comments.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you!